# can't change title navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I can't change the title of my navigationBar in the options view. I am not using Storyboards. I can't add button too.

This is my App Delegate code :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let viewController = MenuTableViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) //ViewController = Name of your controller
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

This is my MenuTabeViewController file

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Options", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleOptions))
}

func handleOptions() {
    let optionViewController = optionsViewController()
    present(optionViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

this is my options file

```
class optionsViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    //I've tried 3 solutions
    self.navigationItem.title = "Options"
    self.title = "Options"
    self.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Options"
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: ops! sorry, my bad :D

Comment: Ahah , No problem  :-)

Comment: which viewcontroller is the rootviewcontroller of your optionsviewcontroller (which itself is a navigationcontroller)?

Comment: It's the MenuTableViewController ? Like i put in the App Delegate ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that `optionsViewController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController`, or is it just because you want it to appear with a navigation bar? If so, containing it within a `UINavigationController` might work better.

Comment: Yes of course, it's because i want that `optionViewController` appear with a navigation Bar, and i don't know how can i do it with an other method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is due to the fact that you're not setting up the new navigation / view controller properly when presenting it.

When presenting your new `UINavigationController`, as you did previously in the `AppDelegate`, you'll want to create a `UIViewController` and set it as the `rootViewController`. So you'll want something like `OptionsNavController` and `OptionsViewController` instead of a single nav controller.

Then in your `OptionsViewController` simple call `self.title = @"Options"`.

**EDIT**

I'm including an example below.

```
func handleOptions() {
    let optionsViewController = OptionsViewController()
    let optionsNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: optionsViewController)
    present(optionsNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

so then as stated above, call `self.title = @"Options"` in `OptionsViewController`.

Comment: Okay, so it's possible to create more than 1 file for 1 view ? ( Option view ). And I don't understand why you said i wanted to create UIViewController while i put `let navigationController = UINavigationController`

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I've included an example in my edits.

Comment: I've tried the code you included in your edit, but i got this error message : `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'`

Comment: `optionsViewController` should subclass `UIViewController` instead of `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Thanks, it's a little bit late, but a didn't saw your answer, and that worked ;)